# Android not running entire function?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have no idea how to better frame this question. I am using JNI to do some image processing. I have three JNI calls, one to do initializations, one to do the image processing (so this one is called multiple times) and one to call all destroy/close methods.

Now my problem is that I am somehow calling the image processing call AFTER destroy. I call destroy on the press of the back button. I am using camera preview so I call this destroy method in onSurfaceDestroyed. I put print statements to debug. These are the relevant code fragments -

```
public void destroy()
{
    destroyTorch(torchState);
    torchState = 0;
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "torchstate in destroy = " + Long.toString(torchState));             
}
```

This is the native function called by above -

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_torchandroid_CameraClass_destroyTorch(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jlong  torchStateLocation)
{
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Torchandroid", "Closing lua state");
   lua_State *L = (lua_State*) torchStateLocation;
   lua_close(L); //Close lua state.
}
```

And this is the native call that does the image processing. The following should not work after the above is called.

```
start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
bProcessing = true;
if(torchState != 0)
{
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Calling torch");
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "torchstate = " + Long.toString(torchState));                
    callTorch(torchState, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, FrameData, pixels); 
}
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, 0, 0, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight);
```

The destroy method calls native which basically destroys any open states. There is a print statement in that native call stating that the call was successful. Now this is the order of the print statements -

```
Closing lua state  //This is a print in native destroyTorch
Calling torch
torchstate = 462345328923482082342 //The pointer that was supposed to be set to 0
```

Now the very fact that "Closing lua state" is output means that the following line, that is setting torchState to 0 should execute. However, it doesn't. I have no idea why this happens but this is causing a stack problem (obviously) because torchstate doesn't exist but gets used in the image processing call.

What's more is that the line "torchstate in destroy" never prints which leads me to believe that part executes after the crash due to the memory leak. Is this because it is in different threads? Why is that? Is there any way to have them run in the same thread? They are, after all, not supposed to be running parallel.

Comment: Where is this line in your statement? 'Log.d("ADebugTag", "torchstate in destroy = " + Long.toString(torchState));' Shouldn't it show up in your print statements? I'm guessing that your onDestroy method isn't being called which isn't setting that pointer to 0

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. It isn't there. However, onDestroy IS being called. Notice how "Closing lua state" gets printed? That is in onDestroy. The program from there should return to java and then execute the next two lines, outputting that log.d statement but it doesn't.

Comment: Is there any chance the functions are called from different threads? Because in that case you should store the torchState locally, set it to 0 and then call the destroyTorch. And it also might be a good idea to synchronize both blocks.

Comment: This was a thread issue. It took me forever to find it so sorry for the delayed response. The two were indeed running in a different thread. I checked for that before posting here since it would be the obvious problem but I could not find it back then. Thanks again.